# How do I know if a view is visible or not?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, animation

Say I have two view controllers: xVC and yVC. I have used the shake API and and have used the methods `-(void)motionBegan`,`-(void)motionEnded:` and `-(void)motionCancelled` in xVC. What happens is when the device is shaken, it fires a simple animation. Now the thing is that this animation is fired even when the I have yVC open that is, when `yVS.view` has been added as the subview. What I am looking for is some if condition which I can use in `-(void)motionEnded:` like this:

```
if(yVC == nil)
{
     //trigger animation
}
```

By that I mean that the shake shouldn't work when yVC is visible. How do I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general advice I have seen and used is to ask a view if it has a non-nil `window` property:

```
if( ! yVC.view.window) {
  // trigger animation
}
```

But note that this doesn't *always* equate with being visible; though in most apps it's about as good as you can performantly get (the basic case where it's not accurate is when a different view completely obscures it, but this may still satisfy your needs)

Answer (score -1):

Add this to both of your view controllers:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated 
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];    
  visible = YES;    
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
  [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
  visible = NO;
}
```

Now, just check the variable isVisible of both the view controllers and trigger your animation likewise.

Answer (score -1):

The previous answers all work to some degree, but fail to take modally presented view controllers into account. If view controller A presents view controller B, of the previous answers will tell you that A is still visible. If you, like me, want to know whether or not the view is actually visible (and not just a part of the view hierarchy), I would suggest also checking the `presentedViewController` property:

```
if (self.isViewLoaded && [self.view window] && !self.presentedViewController) {
    // User is looking at this view and nothing else
}
```

This works since `presentedViewController` will be non-nil whenever the current view controller **OR** any of its ancestors are currently presenting another view controller.